# How to draw a circle above the mapview in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-canvas

I want to draw a circle on the layer ABOVE my Google Maps MapView in Android.
I mean - there is a red circle in the center of the mapview, but wherever I move my map - this cirle should ALWAYS be in the center of my view - something like one layer above mapview.

Can you tell me how to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `FrameLayout`, its first child will be the `MapView`, and its second child will be your circle(with `Gravity` = CENTER).

Comment: But I want to draw something on map too - and my map will be refreshed every 5 min. If it's all ok - could you provide me some example code?

Comment: "draw something on map too" you mean like a layer on the top of the mapview or a pin for a location?

Comment: I mean map overlays with some locations on it. And above it all my "cricle" in the center of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a simple overlay? Something like:

```
public class MapDemo extends MapActivity  { 
    MapView mMapView;
    CircleOverlay mCOverlay;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        GeoPoint mapCentrePoint = new GeoPoint(51500000, 0);
        mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        MapController mapCtrlr = mMapView.getController();
        mapCtrlr.setZoom(8);
        mapCtrlr.setCenter(mapCentrePoint);
        List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mMapView.getOverlays();
        mCOverlay = new CircleOverlay(50.0f);
        listOfOverlays.add(mCOverlay);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {return false;}

    public class CircleOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay {
        Paint mPaint;
        float mRadius;
        public CircleOverlay(float radius) {
            super();
            mRadius = radius;
            mPaint = new Paint();
            mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
            mPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mv, boolean shadow,
                long when) {
            canvas.drawCircle(mv.getWidth()/2, mv.getHeight()/2, 
                    mRadius, mPaint);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not above the map - it's on the map, so when I will move map I won't see my circle in the middle of it - am i right?

Comment: @pawel- The circle will stay fixed in the middle of the view, it will not move with the map. Did you try it?

Answer (score -1):

How about using surfaceview http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html or FrameLayout http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html?

Comment: I see, but IMO FrameLayout isn't way to go, because it blocks my mapView. Did you use surfaceview?

Comment: what about surfaceview I gave you another option

Comment: Try both the options only then consider down voting

Comment: I didn't downvote you - it was someone else. I actually thank you for your interest : )

Comment: sorry then you are welcome and if my answer helps you accept my answer and consider up voting it...:)